# How do I subquery a map for multiple key value combinations in JPA 2.0?

Tags: java, sql, java-ee-7, jpa-2.1

I have the following entity (example):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "person_id", columnDefinition = "UUID")
  private UUID userId;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;


  @ElementCollection
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "phonetype")
  @Column(name = "number")
  @CollectionTable(name = "person_phones", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"))
  private Map<String, String> phoneNumbers;

}
```

Now, the phoneNumbers are String, String in this example. Let's assume the key is the type (like "mobile", "home", "office", "fax", "pager"...) and the value is the actual number in any text format.

I'd like to query for a person which has two phone numbers:

```
Select * From person where
   in his phone_numbers exists phonetype = 'home' and number = '0-123-456'
   and also in his phone_numbers exists phonetype = 'mobile' and number = '9-876-421'
   (and possibly, dynamically others)
   and name = 'John'
```

I already constructed a sql subquery which works:

```
select home.userId from
(
    (SELECT userId from person_phones
    where (phonetype = 'home' and number = '0-123-456'))
) as home,
(
    (SELECT userId from person_phones
    where (phonetype = 'mobile' and number = '9-876-421'))
) as mobile
where home.userId = mobile.userId
```

As said, this is just a sql subquery. I'm writing JPA 2.1 **criteria query** in my project. And this seems oddly complicated. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, solved it using multiple inner joins rather than sub queries.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Person-Test");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    Map<String, String> phoneNumbers = new HashMap<>();
    phoneNumbers.put("home","0-123-456");
    phoneNumbers.put("mobile","9-876-421");

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
    Root<Person> personRoot = query.from(Person.class);
    query.select(personRoot);

    phoneNumbers.forEach((k, v) -> {
        MapJoin<Person, String, String> phoneNrJoinJoin = personRoot.joinMap("phoneNumbers");
        phoneNrJoinJoin.on(cb.equal(phoneNrJoinJoin.key(), k), cb.equal(phoneNrJoinJoin.value(), v));
    });

    query.where(cb.equal(personRoot.get("name"), "John"));

    List<Person> people = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

This results in the following hibernate query (renamed aliases for clarity)

```
SELECT person.person_id, person.name
FROM person 
INNER JOIN person_phones a
ON person.person_id = a.userid
AND (a.phonetype = ? AND a.NUMBER = ?) 
INNER JOIN person_phones b
on person.person_id=b.userId 
and (b.phonetype=? and b.number = ? )
WHERE
person.name = ?;
```

Which returns all tuples of type person where all the mentioned phone numbers match.